# Read a string and store each string in the array when newline character is found

Tags: c, string, linked-list

This program is based on linked list. Read in a string, extract all the substrings separated by newline.

Input should be:

```
hello world\ngood bye\nWhat a nice day!\n\0
```

Then, expected output should be:

```
[hello world]->[good bye]->[What a nice day]->
```

But, when I run the program and type in:

```
hello world\ngood bye\nWhat a nice day!\n\0
```

My output is:

```
[hello world\ngood bye\nWhat a nice day!\n\0]->
```

I tried to read NULL character as '\' and 'n' separately, but couldn't handle it. How can I fix it, to print out as expected output?

---

newTB(char text[]); // function explanation

The function newTB allocates a new textbuffer and initialises its contents with the text given in the array. The lines in the input array are all terminated by a '\n'. The whole text is terminated by a '\0'.

---

char *dumpTB (TB tb);

The following functions do not alter their textbuffer argument. Allocate and return an array containing the text in the given textbuffer. Each individual line of the textbuffer needs to be terminated by a '\n' (this includes the last line). The whole text must be '\0' terminated. It is the caller's responsibility to free the memory occupied by the returned array. If there are no lines in the textbuffer, return NULL.

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct textbuffer *TB;

typedef struct textbuffer {
    char *texts;
    TB next;
} textbuffer;
```

---

```
char *dumpTB (TB tb) {                            // my version of dumpTB
    TB temp = malloc(sizeof(struct textbuffer));
    temp->texts = tb->texts;
    temp->next = NULL;

    return (temp->texts);
}
```

---

```
TB newTB (char text[]){                                // get the array from main function
    TB newText = malloc(sizeof(struct textbuffer));    // return the node
    newText->texts = text;
    //strcpy(newText->texts,text);
    newText->next = NULL;
    return (newText);
}
void printList(TB tb){                    //print entire list
    TB curr = tb;
    while(curr != NULL){
        printf("[%s]-> ",curr->texts);
        curr = curr->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    int i=0;
    int j=0;
    char str[MAX_TEXT];
    char cpy[MAX_TEXT];
    char tmp[MAX_TEXT];
    TB textList = NULL;
    TB list = NULL;
    list = textList;

    fgets(str, MAX_TEXT, stdin);           // input should be like
                                           // hello\nworld\ngood\nbye\n\0
    while(str[i] != '\0') {
        if(str[i] == '\n') {
            cpy[i] = '\0';
            strcpy(tmp,cpy);
            textList = newTB(tmp);
            list = textList;
            textList->texts = dumpTB(textList);
            //TB newList = malloc(sizeof(struct textbuffer));
            //list = textList;
           // newList->texts = textList->texts;
            textList = textList->next;
            j=0;
        }
        cpy[j++] = str[i++];
    }
    printList(list);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You want `cpy[j] = '\0'`

Comment: `'\n'` is a newline character, while your input is two characters, a backslash \ and the letter 'n', so your match never succeeds. Even if you did enter real newlines your program wouldn't do what you want since `fgets` will stop reading at the first newline, yielding "hello".

Comment: I tried both, but still doesn't work.. so which part should i change ??

Comment: fgets is not in the loop. It's out side of the loop to get the input string as 'hello\nworld\ngood\nbye\n\0' such like this.

Comment: You need a piece of work can be interpreted \ and n as '\n' if it.

Comment: also `newText->texts = text;` wrong. Another area is required for each.

Comment: Add `newList->next = NULL;` after the `malloc()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_TEXT 256

typedef struct textbuffer *TB;

typedef struct textbuffer {
    char *texts;
    TB next;
} textbuffer;

TB newTB (char text[]){
    TB newText = malloc(sizeof(struct textbuffer));
    newText->texts = strdup(text);
    newText->next = NULL;
    return newText;
}
void printList(TB tb){
    TB curr = tb;
    while(curr != NULL){
        printf("[%s]-> ",curr->texts);
        curr = curr->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    int i=0;
    int j=0;
    char str[MAX_TEXT];
    char cpy[MAX_TEXT];
//  char tmp[MAX_TEXT];
    TB list    = NULL;
    TB textlist = NULL;

    fgets(str, MAX_TEXT, stdin);//E.g. hello\nworld\ngood\nbye\n\0 -> "hello\\nworld\\ngood\\nbye\\n\\0\n"

    while(str[i] != '\n' && str[i] != '\0') {
        if(str[i] == '\\'){
            if(str[i+1] == 'n') {
                cpy[j] = '\0';
                //strcpy(tmp,cpy);
                TB newList = newTB(cpy);
                if(textlist == NULL)
                    textlist = newList;
                else {
                    textlist->next = newList;
                    textlist = textlist->next;
                }
                if(list == NULL)
                    list = newList;
                j=0;
                i += 2;
            } else if(str[i+1] == '0') {
                break;
            }
        }
        cpy[j++] = str[i++];
    }
    printList(list);
    //deallocate
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wow.. it seems like work properly. :) By the way, what's strdup() in newTB function??

Comment: newText->texts = strdup(text); so is it same as, newText->texts = (char *)malloc((strlen(text)+1)*sizeof(char)); then newText->texts = text; ??

Comment: @BrianSon newText->texts = strdup(text); so is it same as, newText->texts = (char *)malloc((strlen(text)+1)*sizeof(char)); then strcpy(newText->texts , text);

Answer (score 0):

I changed your main function like this:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    int i=0;
    int j=0;
    char str[MAX_TEXT];
    char cpy[MAX_TEXT];
    //char tmp[MAX_TEXT];
    char* tmp = cpy;
    TB textList = NULL;
    TB list = NULL;
    TB newList = NULL;
    //list = textList;

    //fgets(str, MAX_TEXT, stdin);           // input should be like
                                           // hello\nworld\ngood\nbye\n\0
    strcpy(str, "hello\nworld\ngood\nbye\n");

    //  ... or use a file instead of the line above:
    /*
    FILE* f = NULL;
    *str = '\0';
    f = fopen("Sample.txt", "r");
    if (!f)
        return -1;
    (void)fread(str, MAX_TEXT, 1, f);
    fclose(f);
    */

    while(str[i] != '\0') {
        if(str[i] == '\n') {
            //cpy[i] = '\0';
            //strcpy(tmp,cpy);
            //textList = newTB(tmp);
            //TB newList = malloc(sizeof(struct textbuffer));
            //list = textList;
            //newList->texts = textList->texts;
            //textList = textList->next;
            //j=0;

            cpy[j] = '\0';
            newList = newTB(tmp);
            if (textList) {
                textList->next = newList;
                textList = newList;
            }
            else
                list = textList = newList;

            tmp = &cpy[j+1];
        }
        else
        cpy[j] = str[i];

        j++; 
        i++;
    }
    cpy[j] = '\0';
    printList(list);

    // cleanup
    for (textList=list;NULL != textList;) {
        list = textList;
        textList = textList->next;
        free(list);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

`cpy` is the copy of the original string with the newline ('\n') characters replaced with end-of-line characters ('\0'), `tmp` points to the last token in the `cpy`. `list` is the head of your list, `textList` is used as the queue of the list (insertion point for new elements). Furthermore, I replaced `fgets` with `strcpy` because you cannot use `fgets` to get multiple text lines, or you can use a file instead for more text.

I tried to keep your original code as much as possible.

Comment: Maybe `newList = newTB(cpy);`?

Comment: Looks good! :) But, there should be something that allows me to type in.. Later, i should type in quite long text file, and every node should contain a string which is separated by newline..

Comment: You can always use a file: `FILE* f = NULL;
    *str = '\0';
    f = fopen("Sample.txt", "r");
    if (!f)
 return -1;
    (void)fread(str, MAX_TEXT, 1, f);
    fclose(f);`

Comment: I think my explanation was not good enough.. so I edited my code and add some in it.

Comment: I can't see `fgets` as a requirement, I'll add the cleaning code to my answer in a minute.